# How can I force Facebook to purge its cache and use newer meta description of a shared webpage?

Tags: html, facebook, xhtml

Facebook fetches the title and webpage description from the HTML header of the webpage whenever people share a link on Facebook. I realized that [I believe for performance purposes], Facebook caches and reuses the webpage title and description if more people share the same link over and over again. What if the webpage has a breaking news or something that is dynamically changes within a short period of time. Even worse, what if the page had wrong content and the webmaster made changes to it?

How can I force Facebook to flush its cache and update it with new content on the website?

Comment: Are you changing the og tags?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The best way to do it is by using the Facebook debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
Insert your url, let the debugger scrape your page and the cache is cleared.

**UPDATE:**

As DMCS pointed out *"some things cannot be updated after X number of likes"*. Here is the info in more detail taken from the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/):

> Note: `og:title` and `og:type` are only editable initially - after your page
>   receives **50 likes** the title becomes fixed, and after your page
>   receives **10,000 likes** the type becomes fixed. These properties are
>   fixed to avoid surprising users who have liked the page already.
>   Changing the title or type tags after these limits are reached does
>   nothing, your page retains the original title and type.

Comment: Just remember, some things cannot be updated after X number of likes.

Comment: Is it possible to find out the X?

Comment: In [this page](http://www.terryhoward.net/blog/2012/07/20/forcing-facebook-refresh-opengraph-cache/) it recommends you add a random query parameter such as ?fbrefresh=WHATEVER to the end of your URL to ensure that it refreshes. This may help you if for some reason it didn't refresh.