# How to change Facebook og:title after exceeding 50 likes

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

The website http://rekhta.org have title set to "Rekhta : baab-e-sukhan" from the very beginning. But Facebook kept reading the title as "Debugger". I tried all the possible way I could find to change the same.

[Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=rekhta.org) used to show correct title, but the comment box kept showing "Debugger", I thought it is cache issue and gave it some time since the website is launched : 11-Jan-2013.

Now when I tried to change it even the debugger won't show the correct title.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026448/how-can-i-force-facebook-to-purge-its-cache-and-use-newer-meta-description-of-a) thread says

> og:title and og:type are only editable initially - after your page receives **50 likes** the **title becomes fixed**, and after your page receives 10,000 likes the type becomes fixed. These properties are fixed to avoid surprising users who have liked the page already. Changing the title or type tags after these limits are reached does nothing, your page retains the original title and type.

The Facebook support sent me here, please suggest what should I do to resolve this.

"Debugger" - is not even present in my whole project as well as database, confirming after doing a through search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force Facebook to purge its cache and use newer meta description of a shared webpage?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9026448/how-can-i-force-facebook-to-purge-its-cache-and-use-newer-meta-description-of-a)

Comment: No its not duplicate - I have read all of these threads and none solved my problem.

I wanted to contact Facebook supports directly but Facebook support page sent me here.

Comment: You're asking the same question - and the note from the docs regarding the og:title being locked is correct as far as i know

Comment: I am not asking the same question, I know that we have to set og:title for Facebook tag and that it will not change from my end after 50 likes, I want somebody from Facebook support to take a look at it and provide a solution - **unfortunately** [Facebook has officially declared](https://developers.facebook.com/support/) Stack-overflow as their support portal so I have no choice but to post it here. Please remove the negative vote and the answer marked if it is yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised a bug request and Facebook is looking into it. ([link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/141882722641011?browse=search_511c733426a1d2522933470))

They have already cleared the cache on their side :)