# Wrong website meta data is cached

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I created a website and in the first days I set cnn.com as the Facebook open graph URL property when I was experiencing with it. I changed it a few days earlier but still, whenever I post the website on Facebook it adds an image and the cnn meta data to it.

I checked on other computers as well, so it's not a cache problem by my browser.

Example:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.cnn.com/"/>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your URL in the debugger to refresh the Open Graph Tags: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Afaik og-data can be locked when it got a lot of Likes already, see this thread for more information: [How to change Facebook og:title after exceeding 50 likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752689/how-to-change-facebook-ogtitle-after-exceeding-50-likes)

You could file a bug for this though: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Hi, thanks! I already did that, everything looks fine, but cnn still appers when I post the website on Facebook. However, when I post it in a private message, it's showing right data.

Comment: i´ve edited my answer, it´s possible that your tags are locked.

Comment: I will get back to you in 2 days. Btw, the site has not yet been published, so it has 0 likes.

Comment: Yeah, problem still stands. I don't think there is any use in submitting a bug. Facebook may answer in a year..

Comment: i´ve recently submitted a bug and facebook reacted after just one day, just try it :)

Comment: I submitted this as a bug and they replied that they were able to replicate the issue and has been working on it. I'll get back later.

Comment: Facebook got back to me and told me that this was a site wide issue and woul be pushed in a few days. So wow, "Submitting a site wide Facebook bug" is now officially crossed on my bucket list :) (as a matter of fact, the issue seem to have been solved)