# Open Graph score wall post showing incorrect app name

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have Facebook score posting working (/userid/scores with score and app access token) but when it gets posted in the news feed, it is showing an incorrect app name:
[image: Incorrect app name]

[image: Incorrect app name 2]

As you can see, the app name is 'Rockstar Rising' but it is showing as 'vocalist' in the post.  The only place I can think of where 'vocalist' is coming from is from one of our Open Graph Objects, Band Member.

I've tried many different searches without any hits on what might be causing this issue.  I have checked our app settings and code to see if it could be coming from there, but everything looks good.  Is this possible a cache issue or is it something else?

Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem ended up fixing itself.  I'm not sure how, but it could have happened when our game was approved for the app center.  If anyone is having this issue, I'd also take a look at [How can I force Facebook to purge its cache and use newer meta description of a shared webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026448/how-can-i-force-facebook-to-purge-its-cache-and-use-newer-meta-description-of-a)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Make sure you are using the correct app ID whe you call init also check the OpenGraph object and then test them with the lint tool maybe it is a cache issue with facebook.

Comment: I'm thinking this might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026448/how-can-i-force-facebook-to-purge-its-cache-and-use-newer-meta-description-of-a  When I use the Open Graph debug tool, the raw open graph data shows the og:title as being "Rockstar Rising", but I think since X number of people have played the game, the og:title has been set and can't be changed.